# XAMP/Windows - how to load custom php.ini per project

Tags: php, xampp, ini

I have the following environment:

- XAMPP on Windows
- php handled by mod_php5

Can someone please tell me how to load custom php.ini per project? because currently it only loads from the main php.ini of xamp setup.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup PHPINIDir for each virtual host.

Add to your apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot c:\www\example1
ServerName www.example.com
PHPINIDir c:\www\example1

# Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

for handling several virtualhosts you should have different hostnames (you can use etc/hosts) or different ip-adresses.

Comment: I thought this looked good but it doesn't work. I get an error: only first PHPINIDir directive honored, even though there is only one in the conf.